# How to locate & identify identical sections in multiple files?

Tags: regex, bash, diff, matching

I have about 30 files (markdown but that's mostly beside the point), and some of the files were created by copy/pasting sections from other files, so there's lots of duplication. I want to remove the duplicate sections to external "module" files so I can edit Section A in `SectionA.md` then include in each file that needs that section.

I want:

1. identical sections less than 4 lines ignored
2. the complete text of each repeated section
3. the name of the files in which that section appears

How can I achieve this?

Note: **the process doesn't need to be 100% automated & 100% perfect.** If there's a quick solution that dumps all the matches & filenames & I have to sort thru it some by hand, that's fine. This is a one-off task so expediency trumps robustness

### Current Thoughts

- I'm looking into using `diff` as I know it can identify identical portions of files, but I'm not sure how to map this to 30 files
- I could write a program to do this (in Node just because that's what I'm familiar with) but this would probably take more time than just going thru all 30 files manually, so I disprefer this solution.

Comment: you can have a look to `comm`, with the `-12` option.  However, since it expects sorted inputs it won't be 100% accurate for text files.